# Unity Camera Clamp Any Orthographic size

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, orthographic

I would like to limit the range of the camera so that only a certain range of Unity's Orthographic camera size changes. If the size is 5, and the camera's x maximum range is 10, then at 3 it is about 11.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit more? It's not quite obvious what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to limit the movement of the camera. For example, assuming the screen is 1920x1080, if the screen size is 1920x1080, it will not move because the whole screen is shown. However, if the size is changed to 1280x760, I would like to move the screen freely within the size of 1920x1080.